# Download temp file from website using python return 500

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to get automatically download a file from a website using requests.

When I go to this webpage https://statistikbanken.dk/statbank5a/default.asp?w=1448 and open a table to download, I find that it opens this link

[https://statistikbanken.dk/statbank5a/selectout/ready.asp?PLanguage=0&pxfile=D:\ftproot\LocalUser\statbank\statbank5a\Temp\202381019834427555087BIL5.px&outfile=D:\ftproot\LocalUser\statbank\statbank5a\Temp\202381019834427555087BIL5&queryfile=202381019834427555087BIL5&Pxsid=](https://statistikbanken.dk/statbank5a/selectout/ready.asp?PLanguage=0&pxfile=D:%5Cftproot%5CLocalUser%5Cstatbank%5Cstatbank5a%5CTemp%5C202381019834427555087BIL5.px&outfile=D:%5Cftproot%5CLocalUser%5Cstatbank%5Cstatbank5a%5CTemp%5C202381019834427555087BIL5&queryfile=202381019834427555087BIL5&Pxsid=)

Which creates the file. But when I try to make a post or get request to this link I get return code 500

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you check if there are cookies involved?

Comment: [This](https://statistikbanken.dk/statbank5a/selectout/print.asp?pxfile=D:\ftproot\LocalUser\statbank\statbank5a\Temp\2023810192159427556113BIL54.px&outfile=D:\ftproot\LocalUser\statbank\statbank5a\Temp\2023810192159427556113BIL54&FileformatId=20&Queryfile=2023810192159427556113BIL54&PLanguage=0&MainTable=BIL54&MainTablePrestext=Bestand%20af%20motork%F8ret%F8jer%20efter%20omr%E5de,%20k%F8ret%F8jstype,%20brugerforhold%20og%20drivmiddel&potsize=1&Buttons=5&TableStyle=) link downloads just fine. How did you get to that link, could you walk us through? I hope that's not a government site. :(

Comment: @doneforaiur. I looked in the network in developer tools. When I try the link you posted, I get an error page.

where did you find yours?

Comment: Interesting, it does open on my machine with Firefox and Chrome. I also tried deleting cookies and directly clicked on my link and it worked. I clicked `BIL54`, and then `ANNULER` and then `Udskriv` to get the link.